# How to interact with camera roll in Xamarin.UITesting?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I have been trying to tap on Camera Roll in Xamarin.iOS, using Xamarin.UITesting when it opens in my application but as it is part of the OS, I am unable to use Tap function to select the camera roll and then an image. Using the app.Repl() , it just appears as this:

```
[CalabashRootView]                                                              
  [UIWindow > ... > UILayoutContainerView]
    [UINavigationTransitionView > ... > _UISizeTrackingView]
      [_UIRemoteView] id: "RemoteViewBridge"
    [UINavigationBar] id: "Photos"
      [_UIBarBackground]
        [UIImageView]
        [UIVisualEffectView]
          [_UIVisualEffectBackdropView]
          [_UIVisualEffectSubview]
      [_UINavigationBarContentView]
        [_UIButtonBarStackView]
          [_UIButtonBarButton] label: "Cancel"
            [_UIModernBarButton] label: "Cancel"
              [UIButtonLabel] label: "Cancel",  text: "Cancel"
        [UILabel] label: "Photos",  text: "Photos"
      [UILabel] label: "Photos",  text: "Photos"
      [_UIButtonBarButton] label: "Cancel"
        [_UIModernBarButton] label: "Cancel"
          [UIButtonLabel] label: "Cancel",  text: "Cancel"
  [UIWindow > UILayoutContainerView]
    [UINavigationTransitionView > ... > UITableView]
      [WelcomeScreenCustomCell]
        [UITableViewCellContentView]
          [UIView]
```

I have tried to just push an image into the photo selection process through a backdoor but I can't seem to get it working properly (this is my AppDelegate):

```
    [Export("selectImageFromCameraRoll:")] // notice the colon at the end of the method name
    public NSString SelectImage(NSString value)
    {
        UIImage photo = UIImage.FromFile("testImage.jpg");
        NSData imgData = photo.AsJPEG(0.6f);
        UIImage img = new UIImage(imgData);
        var vc = window.RootViewController;

        //not working
        ((UIDataViewController)vc.Handle).TakenPhoto(img);
        return new NSString("true");
    }
```

Has anyone had any experience of this and is there a way to just select an image?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the plugin **MediaPlugin** from Nuget .

Don't forget to add **NSCameraUsageDescription** and **NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription** in indo.plist in order to access the device's camera and photo/video library.

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the camera to take photos.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to photos.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to microphone.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to the photo gallery.</string>
```

And you could better call the code in MainViewController

```
async void TakePhoto()
    {
        await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            // No camera available.
            return;
        }

        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });

        if (file == null)
            return;

        var ImagePath = file.Path;
        //... do something you want
    }
```